# vim not echoing message after make

Tags: vim

Consider a the following minimal vimrc:

```
set nocompatible

filetype plugin indent on
let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'

function! CompileLatex()
    let save_pwd = getcwd()
    lcd %:p:h
    let compiler = 'pdflatex '
    let mainfile = expand('%:p:r')
    let &l:makeprg = compiler . mainfile . '.tex'
    echon "compiling latex file..."
    silent make!
    execute 'lcd ' . save_pwd
endfunction

function! EchoLatexMessage()
    redraw
    echo 'This message is not shown'
endfunction

augroup echo_message
    au!
    au QuickFixCmdPost make call EchoLatexMessage()
augroup END
```

And in a `foo.tex` file like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

run `:call CompileLatex()`. As seen in the GIF the message `This message is not shown` from function `EchoLatexMessage()` is not shown (on the other hand the message `compiling latex file...` is always on screen).  Why is this happening? I expect the new message to be echoed once `:make` finishes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `silent make!` in your function. The `:silent` apparently not only applies to the `:make` itself, but also to the autocmds invoked by it (which sort of makes sense). If you want to silence the compilation output itself, but not the messages from the autocmd, you can prepend `:unsilent` to `:echo` in the `EchoLatexMessage()` function.